# How to measure the amount of time taken by program

Tags: c++, valgrind

I want to measure the time taken by my C++ program however, if I use:

```
time_t begin, end;
time_t(&begin);
func(); //my function...it contains the code whose elapsed time I want to measure
time(&end);
cout<<"\n Time elapsed:"<<difftime(end, begin) <<" seconds"<<endl;
```

The time elapsed that I am getting is 0 seconds.

Also gprof does not work in my case as it shows that it cannot allocate the amount of memory, as is required by my program.

Is there some other way out to measure the amount of time required by my program. Valgrind's massif tool does show the time taken by the snapshot but the documentation does not mention whether it is in milliseconds or microseconds.

Please suggest a suitable way?

It would be nice if i can measure the time in milli-seconds.

Comment: Use `time` utility in shell? Assuming you are running *nix. Or you can use C function `clock()` to count clock ticks.

Comment: I used but it still gives me..that the time elapsed is 0

Comment: You have to call time once before the function and once after the function. It seems that you forgot to record the time before the function.

Comment: Sorry ...my bad...did a typo error :(   But the problem continues to remain the same.

Comment: `time` utility in shell usually will give you back the time in millisec, assuming that the function you want to time is the only thing in the program. It also counts the time the program spends outside the function, though.

Comment: Can u please give an example of its usage or some good link...i am a novice at it.

Comment: *nix also has a built in manual which can give you examples of commands $ man time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::chrono.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

you may also want to look at facebook's benchmarking utility.
https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Benchmark.md

Answer (score 0):

You could use code as shown below.

```
clock_t start = clock();     
 // Code here...
clock_t ticks = clock()-start;     
std::cout << "Time Taken:" << (double)ticks/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
```

Comment: Does it give me time in milliseconds?

Comment: This does give time in ms. But the accuracy depends on the granularity of the system. Typically it is 15.6ms on a Windows system. That means you would only see time which is the multiple of 15.6 ms.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to spawn the program yourself (`CreateProcess` on Windows, `fork` on Unix-like systems). Then, wait for the child to exit (`WaitForSingleObject` on Windows, `waitpid` on Unix). Finally, get the times for the child process (`GetProcessTimes` on Windows, `times` on Unix).

This will give times in milliseconds, and separates wall time from CPU time. The latter is particularly handy when/if you have other stuff running on the same system at the same time (you still get better accuracy with a quiescent system, but can stay reasonably close).